# Proper way to set the style of a custom typeface in Android

Tags: android, fonts, typeface, android-typeface

I downloaded a font to include on my Android project.

Now, do I need to also include the "bold" and "italic" versions of the font to my assets or do I need only the regular one? And if I do so, do I need to manually `setTypeface(getBoldFont(), Typeface.BOLD)` for bold (and for italic) or does Android automatically get it done for me?

Comment: You need the bold and italic versions as well.

Comment: @Rotwang So I need to manually set the typeface? But what style flag do I use? I assume it will be double "bolded" if I use BOLD flag on a bold typeface.

Comment: **NO**. You can only use the bold flag on a bold typeface. Using bold on a non bold typeface won't set it bold. These "flags" only work by choosing the proper typeface - **if** you provide it.

Answer (score 3):

Download the following 4 types of the font: normal, bold, italic, bold_italic. Then create a CustomFont class as follows:

```
public class CustomFont {
    Context context;
    public CustomFont(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Typeface setNormalFont() {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/normal.ttf");
        return  typeface;
    }

    public Typeface setBoldFont () {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/bold.ttf");
        return typeface;
    }

    public Typeface setItalick() {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/italic.ttf");
        return typeface;
    }

    public Typeface setItalickBold() {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/italic_bold.ttf");
        return typeface;
    }
}
```

Then when you want to set font on any view, you can use the following code to use the desired font:

```
CustomFont customFont = new CustomFont(this);
textView.setTypeFace(customFont.setNormalFont());
```